# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'd1' to data type int

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a column in the table of `Varchar` data type. Before inserting data in this field I am retrieving maximum value from the table using this query:

```
string max = g1.retrieve_val("select isnull(max(cast(substring(aid,3,(len(aid)-1)) as int)+1),1) from tbl_name");
max = "aid" + max;
```

Then using insert query to enter data in this field. But while doing this I am getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'd1' to data type int

Please guide me how can I rectify this? Am I doing something wrong? Although I have used the same approach in other tables, there I was no getting any error. But in this particular able I am getting this error.

Comment: What type is the column in the table? int?

Comment: Data Type is Varchar. And column name is AID

Comment: Clearly you can't convert `'d1'` to an integer, since it's not a numeric value.  And it would seem that `'d1'` is the value you're selecting.  What is `aid`?  If you want to convert it to an integer then you need to get only numeric characters from it.

Comment: Please share any one value of AID Column

Comment: @David AID is my column name and I want to insert values like this- aid1,aid2,...etc

Comment: @HiralNayak I have inserted a value in this field like this- aid1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select isnull(max(cast(substring(aid,4,1) as int)+1),1) from tbl_name
```

Answer (score 0):

*Am I doing something wrong?*

Yes, you're trying to convert the varchar value `d1` to an int. This will fail.

*How can I rectify this?*

If you simply want to disregard all non-integer rows, you can filter these out *first*, before casting to int. If your RDBMS supports character classes in LIKE clauses, you can try:

```
WHERE substring(aid,3,(len(aid)-1))) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Otherwise, you will have to decide what to do with values such as `d1`, and convert them appropriately.

Comment: Ok. Then how should I write my query???
Should I write like this-
`select isnull(max(cast(substring(aid,3,(len(aid)-1)) where substring(aid,3,(len(aid)-1)) Not Like '%[^0-9]%' as int)+1),1) from tbl_name`

Comment: No, just add it to the query as a normal where clause. The filtering will be done before the expression is evaluated

Comment: Ok like this-
select aid WHERE substring(aid,3,(len(aid)-1)) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' from tbl_name

Comment: Right, or in your query `select isnull(...) where ... from tbl_name`

Comment: Sir, sorry but I am totally confused.
Currently I am using this query-`select isnull(max(cast(substring(aid,3,(len(aid)-1)) as int)+1),1) from accessories`
According to you please guide me how can I modify my query?

Comment: `select isnull(max(cast(substring(aid,3,(len(aid)-1)) as int)+1),1) WHERE substring(aid,3,(len(aid)-1)) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' from accessories`

Comment: After using this query it says Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'

Comment: Ok, so I was missing a close parentheses...You should have been able to debug this though rather than just coming back for another spoonful... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
cnx.cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Usuario(id,nombre,apellido) VALUES((SELECT CONVERT(int,(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id)+1,1) FROM Usuario))),'" + Nombre + "','" + Apellido + "')", cnx.cn);
```